# Checking if one point from sf object falls within a specific polygon from different sf object in R

Tags: r, sf, intersect, within

I have one sf object in R that consists of millions of GPS points of different persons (each point includes ID for each user). I have another sf object that consists of polygons that correspond to 100-meter buffers around the same individuals' residences (approx. 800 buffers). This second polygon sf object also includes user ids.

I need to include a column in the attribute table of the point sf object that takes two values, 0 or 1, indicating whether that point falls within (1) or outside (0) of that person's very own residential buffer. Note that the challenge is not to detect if points fall within ANY of the buffers, but specifically for the buffer that corresponds to that same person.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using st_intersects and then looking up the matching ID values?